# How can we enable DNS Resolver functionality same as in Windows in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

In Windows Operating System DNS resolver is used to resolve external Websites in which it points to Google or Cloudfare & store in DNS Cache. AD servers are connected to this DNS Resolver for internal usage. I would like enable this DNS resolver functionality in Ubuntu 20 OS. How is this possible ? Any help is highly appreciated ?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is – Ubuntu makes use of DNS, just like any other modern operating systems.

Comment: Not knowing whether you have a local DNS server or not, look at `/etc/resolv.conf` and `man resolv.conf`.

Comment: Did you want to set up your own local DNS server? If so, that can be done with a number of DNS servers. Bind9 may be one of the more common options. There is even a [Ubuntu doc](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns) for setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

Having dug into this quite recently, I can tell you you are about to open a cesspool you won't believe.

Linux distributions are at this time all in flux on this (local resolving) and any solution will be temporary and applicable to a certain environment only.

The problems are mainly caused by the will of everyone to solve the limitations of the classical way of resolving (/etc/nsswitch + /etc/resolv.conf), combined with new technologies (IPv6, systemd, DNS-over-HTTPS) and their implementations through different conflicting older and newer software packages (systemd, iproute2, NetworkManager, ifupdown, eni, dnsmasq, resolver, netplan.io).

You are lucky with Ubuntu, which uses systemd exclusively. *Please avoid any other package*. Dig (among others) into the following files, directories, commands and services:

```
/bin/networkctl
/etc/systemd/networkd.conf
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf
/etc/systemd/network/
systemd-networkd.service 
systemd-resolved.service
```

Good luck.